# Why no developer exception page in asp.net 5 razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor-pages, asp.net5

I have a simple asp.net 5 razor pages app which does not show developer exception page but shows this in the browser developer tools

```
The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.
```

After many iterations and debugging it turns out there was a simple typo in the sql query and instead of showing the developer error page, it was showing blank with the aforementioned error in the browser console !

Questions -

- Is this normal/expected ?
- any way to turn on "more" debugging to identify such errors rather than trial and error ?

environment -

- Visual studio 2019, .net 5
- db access using dapper v2.0.78
- configure excerpts below !

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logg)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
              ...
```

there are no try/catch handlers, the code is rather basic
in the razor page

```
        public IEnumerable<gEmployee> ListRows { get; private set; }
        DAL mDAL;
        public string Message;

        public void OnGet(int dID)
        {
            ListRows = mDAL.GetEmployees(dID);

            Message = $"Got {ListRows.Count()} Rows";            
        }
```

this is how i figured out the error when the OnGet() would get called but 2nd line with Message = ListRows.Count would not get executed !!

in GetEmployees

```
        public List<gEmployee> GetEmployees(int dID)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cx.DefaultConnection))
            {
                var sql = @"SELECT * from gEmployee ";
                if (dID > 0)
                    sql += " WHERE dID = @dID ";

                var ListRows = conn.Query<gEmployee>(sql, new { dID = dID}).ToList();
                return ListRows;
            }

        }
```

Comment: More of a comment: Perhaps this can serve as a motivation to write some test cases to ensure the SQL can be rendered correctly?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a new,clean project?

Comment: @GeorgeVovos thanks for the tip, it turns out the services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter(); was the problem, still early stages on the development but taking it out works ! thanks again !

Comment: @Kumar: Since it sounds like you’ve identified the solution, I’d recommend posting it as an answer and accepting it. (You can’t award your own bounty to yourself, but that’ll at least make it clear to future readers what the resolution was.)

Comment: @JeremyCaney good idea, think it should be awarded to George if anyone for pointing the way, will ask him, can't tag two commenters apparently, don't know it's a bug or a feature !

Comment: @GeorgeVovos I think the bounty should go to you if you can post it as an answer

Comment: It feels silly posting someone else's answer just to get a few points... I'll shamelessly do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in these cases, the first approach should be trying to reproduce the behaviour on a small/clean project so you can rule out various scenarios.

As you saw, in your case it's the

```
 services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter()
```

that is causing the problem.
As [Microsoft says in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.databasedeveloperpageexceptionfilterserviceextensions.adddatabasedeveloperpageexceptionfilter?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

> This should only be enabled in the Development environment.

Answer (score 0):

The developer error page will display in the event of an exception being raised in your server-side code. Based on the console message, it is likely that your SQL typo did not cause an exception to be raised. Or, if it did, you might be hiding it in a `try - catch` block. You haven't actually shown the relevant code so this is pure speculation. Either way, it resulted in your view page trying to render something that the browser did not understand, so the browser let you know in the console.

If you are writing SQL, it is always useful to test it in SQL Server Management Studio prior to handing it over to your code to execute.

Comment: If there was a try/catch handler then there will be some content on the page from the menu etc rather than a blank page with that text in the console ! but i have updated the question above

Answer (score 0):

> Is this normal/expected

You're working with an advanced framework (.net) for the web development, so, debugging is **not** as simple as other platforms (like PHP frameworks) unless you know enough about the the project dependencies and underlying details/behaviors. In this way, you may sometimes see none relevant or ambiguous errors. In my opinion, working with high level frameworks requires a greater level of knowledge and experience. In your case, **primarily double check methods and attributes to be used deliberately** as they can disable/disturb the built-in Exception Handler behavior where you said *instead of showing the developer error page, it was showing blank with the aforementioned error in the browser console*

> any way to turn on "more" debugging to identify such errors rather
> than trial and error ?

You can write a *HandleError* method containing one of the approaches available at [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to consume where you need it like this :

```
private void HandleError()
{
    ...
    var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
    ....
}

public void OnGet(string code)
{
    //do stuff
    HandleError();
    //return
}
```

Please read the entire of MS Doc page in order to find out which one well fits in your case to unravel the main problem. After clearing the issue, you no more need to use above technique.